# How to make text type itself with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way where jQuery can make text type itself? Like someone is typing in the letters but it is really jQuery doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to write my own so I'm a little bit behind the other answers. Here's something I quickly put together, it seems to run pretty good.

```
var text = "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
var charCount = text.length;
var currentLetterCount = 0;
var speed = 100; // How fast should it type?
var $input = document.getElementById("someInput");

function writeLetter() {
    var currentText = $input.value;
    var currentLetter = text.charAt(currentLetterCount);
    currentLetterCount++;
    $input.value = currentText + currentLetter;
    if(currentLetterCount == charCount)
        clearInterval(timerId);
}

var timerId = setInterval(writeLetter, speed);
```

**Here's a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7K3UE/) and how to use it with a class instead of an ID.**

Comment: How can I put this in a .click() function?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/typewriter-typer-text-animation) for it

You can use it to type out elements like this:

```
$('.exampleA_Header').jTypeWriter();
```

Comment: This is becoming like "There's an app for that".

Comment: He´s asking how to do it with jQuery. jQuery is an library who already makes everything easy by that principle.

Comment: I'm still waiting for something that will do my dishes and laundry, there oughta be plugin for that :)

Comment: xD I understand, but to be honest. Using libraries and plugins is a big part of being a programmer.

Comment: No I agree it's just that my dishes are dirty :) Plugins need to be chosen carefully depending on the functionality they require. A **LOT** of times I see developers using plugins for the simplest of functionality that can be written in 15 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery - just set up a string, some timers with a bit of random in them and copy characters into a DIV one at a time. Pure JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery is pure JavaScript. And you don't need to jQuery to do *anything*, but it might make it easier.

Comment: Thats why I would like a jQuery way haha

Comment: I agree, but for many is it a crutch that prevents them from thinking of the fundamentals first.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that updating an element on a timer would get the job done.

untested, but off the top of my head, note that this does not use jquery, but would be easily converted.

```
var timer = 0;

timer = setInterval ( "updateElement()", 5000 );

function updateElement ( )
{
  var stringToType = "this text will be typed";
  var oldValue = getElementById('myelement').Value;

if(stringToType == oldValue)
{
  clearInterval(timer);
}  
else
{
  getElementById('myelement').Value = oldValue + stringToType.subString(oldValue.length, 1);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you put this in a .click() function and where would I put in a element with a class?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Javascript itself could do it with setInterval and a string you want to print, setting innerText/textContent of an element.